# Spring Security's "isAuthenticated()" expression really necessary when used with "hasRole()"?

Tags: spring-security

I need a clarification about **Spring Security `isAuthenticated()`** built-in expression.

See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) for documentation.

I would like to know whether or not it is really necessary or plain redundant to use `isAuthenticated()` when the `hasRole()` expression is also used.

Comment: In documentation you have seen that `isAuthenticated()` is to check whether user is logged in or anonymous. `hasRole([role])` is used to check whether user has the specified role (authority), e.g like 'admin', 'viewableIdentityNo',...so on.

Comment: Thanks but that does not answer my question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, yes it would be unnecessary. The `isAuthenticated()` expression's purpose is to allow you to allow access for authenticated users regardless of what roles they have.

Unless you use `hasRole()` in a contrived way (e.g. by selecting the role assigned to anonymous users), then there's no reason why you would also need to add `isAuthenticated()`, since only authenticated users will have the roles you assign to them in your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot Luke. I was asking because I was wondering whether isAuthenticated was really necessary [here in roo service layer addon](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/blob/master/addon-layers-service/src/main/java/org/springframework/roo/addon/layers/service/ServiceClassMetadata.java#L229).

Comment: Also see related roo jira [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3487). I am in the process of creating a pull request to sort this bug.

Comment: When you have isAuthenticated for an url pattern, how spring ensures that the user is already authenticated?